# Different behaviour of new Activities launched from singleInstance Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a simple app. The first (launch) Activity is marked in the manifest as

```
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

[The docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) state that:

> A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other
>   activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task.
>   **If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a
>   different task** (...)

So when I launch a second activity from my first (`singleInstance`) activity on a Samsung device on Android 5.1, hit the overview button, the result is as expected: the second activity was started on an own task:

[image: Test app on Samsung]

On a Nexus 5x running 6.0.1 (and also on emulators running Android 5.1) though, the second activity seems to be on the same task:

[image: Test app on Nexus 5x]

What is the reason for this?

Am I right that the behaviour of the Samsung device is the one to be expected from the docs mentioned above?

Is Samsung actually doing something right that the others dont?

My simple test app can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/asco33/throwaway333).

Comment: I am also occur this problem...Solved by using  android:launchMode="singleTask"

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is actually the same on both devices. `singleInstance` is supposed to open a new task for every activity. Running your app on a samsung and a nexus, a new task is opened. However, the recent app or overview screen work differently on each device  (as you can see with close all not being present in Nexus). On the Nexus, a new task does not mean a new spot in the overview screen. It will still open a new task, but the task where it was opened from will be put in the background and may not be visible. On Samsung, they have chosen to show all tasks background or foreground, and this is just their design choice. To get the behavior you want on all devices, you need to use `documentLaunchMode` [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#dlmode). This guarantees that a new task will be made **and** will show up in the overview screen as a new task [more docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html).